# Which is more preferable? Performance or Memory while spliting a string in C#?

Tags: c#, performance, unity-game-engine

I would like to ask that which case of the two below is more preferable than the other considering garbage collection, memory and cpu usage in C#.

```
a = data.Split('|')[0];
b = data.Split('|')[1];
c = data.Split('|')[2];
d = data.Split('|')[3];
e = data.Split('|')[4];
```

or

```
string[] splitedData = data.Split('|');

a= splitedData[0];
b = splitedData[1];
c = splitedData[2];
d = splitedData[3];
e = splitedData[4];
```

I would prefer the second one since I think holding the splited data array reference and accessing from using that reference is less cpu-intensive and uses less memory access.

The first one uses more cpu and creates an array at each time (filling and accessing the array requires also more memory operation) in order to get the data accordingly.

I am asking this question because I saw in a game project created by Chupamobile that the first one was used.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What _benefits_ do you see from the first method?  It just looks like lazy programming to me.

Comment: a) Not every piece of code you'll ever encounter has been perfectly tuned for maximum performance, and b) most pieces of code never *need* to be tuned for maximum performance.

Comment: There is no "performance or memory" involved in this question, the first example is just bad.

Comment: @martinstoeckli why is the first example bad?

Comment: The first example does the same work 5 times and each time it allocates memory to create an array.

Comment: @martinstoeckli it is just unfair saying that my question does not involve "performance or memory" while your answer is answering my question by using "performance and memory".

Comment: @aod - I do not understand nor appreciate the many downvotes, because there is actually something to learn in this question. The problem with the first example is, that it is slower **and** needs more memory, so it is no tradeoff between the two. It is important to understand, that the first example does create 5 arrays, each time using one of the elements and then throws away the array.

Comment: Yes I totally aggree wtih you. Although I was completely sure that the second one is better, it confused me since it is used in a code written by ChupaMobile which is a big company selling many big game templates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no reason to do a computation that has the same result multiple times, especially if it involves memory allocations. You're correct in that your first snippet has worse time and memory performance.

Every call to split will iterate over the string (probably the fastest part of all that), allocate two new arrays and copy a lot of substrings around. For operations such as this you should always store the result instead of making two calls.

*Technically* even property accesses can be stored with a very minor performance gain, but most of the time you shouldn't bother unless in situations like above.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to repeat the same split operation...
The best is:

```
string[] splitedData = data.Split('|');

a= splitedData[0];
b = splitedData[1];
c = splitedData[2];
d = splitedData[3];
e = splitedData[4];
```